# UIView not displaying

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, swift3

I am trying to create a simple UIView by calling the following function:

```
func loadCell() {
    let cell : UIView!
    cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50))
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00)
    self.view?.addSubview(cell)
    print("Test")
}
```

I do not get any errors, however the UIView doesn't seem to appear. The text "Test" is printed to the console which tells me it's not a function calling problem. Another thing to note is that I use the exact same code in a different function at a different part of my program to create a different UIView and that code works perfectly. I have absolutely no idea why this code isn't working. At first I thought it may be a zPosition issue, but after experimenting with the zPosition I see no difference.

I then thought it may have something to do with there already being other UIViews being displayed at the time of calling the function, and the new one that the function "should" be creating isn't getting displayed because the program is thinking "It's ok, you already have a UIView here sir! No need to display another!", as strange as that may be.

Update:
I am calling the loadCell function inside of another function called `drawGrid()`. drawGrid() is simple a nested for loop which creates a grid of UIViews x along and y high. The drawGrid() function works perfectly when spawning in level 1, however once level 1 is complete and I try to spawn in level 2 that is when it doesn't spawn the next set of UIViews. It prints all of my `print("Test")`s to the console multiple times which tells me it IS getting to that point in the program but doesn't want to create the next grid of UIViews.

Update 2:

```
var gridSizeX:Int = 10
var gridSizeY:Int = 10
var gridArray: [[UIView?]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: gridSizeY), count: gridSizeX)

func loadCell(xPos:Int, yPos:Int) {
    let xStart = Int(size.width/2/2) - ((gridSizeX * gridScale)/2)
    let yStart = Int(size.height/2/2) - ((gridSizeY * gridScale)/2)

    let cell : UIView!
    cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xStart + (xPos * gridScale), y:yStart + (yPos * gridScale), width:gridScale, height:gridScale))

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02).cgColor
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0)

    self.view?.addSubview(cell)

    gridArray[xPos][yPos] = cell
}

func drawGrid() {
    for y in 0 ... gridSizeY {
        for x in 0 ... gridSizeX {
            loadCell(xPos:x, yPos:y)
        }
    }
}


func breakGrid() {
    for y in 0 ... gridSizeY - 1 {
        for x in 0 ... gridSizeX - 1 {
            gridArray[x][y]?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the functions I posted here at the beginning are a little different as I removed unnecessary, irrelevant code not to get confused by. I have added it all back here, and if there is anything you are unsure about just ask :) I also added the "BreakGrid()" function with deletes/removes the previous grid of UIViews. and after deleted I run the drawGrid() again for the next level.

Comment: What does it show when you `print(self.view)`?

Comment: I have checked it and your code works perfectly for me

Comment: When I do `print(self.view)` it just prints `nil`. So that may be where the problem is then. I have no idea why it would be doing that since Xcoder123 just stated it works, but doesn't want to in my project. Quite strange indeed

Comment: Another Update: When I do `print(cell)` is prints `<UIView: 0x10122d820; frame = (50 50; 50 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x1742242e0>>`. So on the other hand it seems like it should be working. I fear something else in my program is interfering with the spawning of the cell.

Comment: Please post more code to find out why `self.view == nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely calling your method too early, before your view is initialized (probably calling from viewDidLoad?). This would explain why print(self.view) is nil

Try calling your method for viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    loadCell()
}
```

Comment: When I attempt this solution, I get two errors. 1: "Method does not override any method from its superclass" and 2: "Value of type SKScene has no member 'viewWillAppear' ".

Comment: Where you calling your method from? in a UIViewController class? a UIView class?

Comment: OK, obviously you are working with a SKScene. 
Have you set the camera of your SKScene? the anchorPoint? the size? The camera node in the scene that determines what part of the scene’s coordinate space is visible in the view.

Comment: also, you should probably call your loadCell() in 
'func sceneDidLoad() { 
super.sceneDidLoad()

loadCell()
}'

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Swift and it is quite hard to understand all of this. All I know is that I didn't have to do any camera/anchorPoint things for all of my other UIViews I've got working. This specific one doesn't want to work. The function is inside another function "drawGrid()" which loops x*y times to draw a grid. so for each x/y value it will call the loadCell() func to spawn a grid square there, and so on. So I call the drawGrid() func on program start, which loads level 1. but once that level is complete and I try to delete level 1 and load level 2 it doesn't want to print the new cells

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code where you delete level 2 as well as the code where you define the class in which loadCell() is?

Comment: loadCell() is defined and called from inside `class GameScene: SKScene`. However, I am using `.removeFromSuperview()` in a loop to remove the old cells. Perhaps this is what is causing the issue? I'm creating a cell called `cell` and putting it into an array of cells to display a grid. Each cell is one square in the grid. later on I am deleting the entire array of `cell`s (grid) and then calling the function again to spawn another grid of UIViews with the same variable name `cell`. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: I think this is the issue, however, if you don't put the full code of what you've just described here, in your question above (by editing it) I will not be able to help you any further

Comment: Updated, with additional functions. Take a look now

Answer (score 0):

> When I do print(self.view) it just prints nil

That means that your `self.view` is `nil` so nothing subviews your cell. You should check why your view is `nil`. Probably it has not been added to `self` by the time `loadCell()` is called.

So focus on why the view is `nil`.

Comment: I'm not too sure what would/could cause it to be nil. Is there anything you could suggest that could help me locate why it would be printing nil?

Comment: @Terminal It would be nice if you edited your post and added the code showing where you call `loadCell()` and where you initialize the `self`. Any code related would be helpful :) But generally speaking you can just place `print(self.view)` at like every function and watch where it transforms to `nil`. Better practice is to use breakpoints of course

Comment: I did what you suggested and placed a `print(self.view)` after every line in the function and it prints `nil` every single time. I tried changing the variable name incase there is another instance of the name `cell` somewhere else in the program but the problem is there there. And I call `loadCell()` inside of another function called `drawGrid()` which loops x*y number of times to create a grid of UIViews x*y number of times.

Comment: @Terminal Can' comment on the neighbouring answer.. I agree with Ocunidee, it is tough to help without looking at the code which has `loadCell()` in it. And about `print()` - I probably didn't say it clear, I meant that you should check if `self.view` is nil before calling `loadCell()` and where it becomes `nil`. And indeed it is more likely connected to `.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code it's work perfect. May your view not updated properly. Can you try this on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let cell : UIView!
        cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00)
        self.view.addSubview(cell)
        print("Test")
    }
```

Comment: Tried this solution but still doesn't seem to want to display the UIView

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 func loadCell() {
        let cell : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00)
        self.view?.addSubview(cell)
        print("Test")
        print(self.view)
    }
```

It may be work for you
I have given the size at the time of initialization.

Comment: This won't make a difference.

Comment: So? Many other users have identified that the above code works for them. But your answer does not change anything about his code. Whether he initializes in one line or on the next line will not solve his problem.